# ASP.Net MVC Displaying a session value in a master page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

When I display a session value in a master page (`<%: Session["companyname"].ToString() %>`) the following information is displayed on the page `{ CompanyName = TestCompany}`. How do I get just the value?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show the code where the value is stored in the session?

Comment: I'd say the object stored at `Session["companyname"]` is not a `string` but made of a class that implements a custom `.ToString()` override.

Comment: @hangy - I suspect an anonymous object, but without the code it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can show the code where the value is stored in the session, it's more likely that I could help.  I would suggest, though, that you might want to reconsider using the value from the session directly in your view.  It would be better, in my opinion, to have a base view model that all of your view models derive from that has the CompanyName property, and any other common properties required by your master page, on it.  Your master page, then, could be strongly-typed to the base view model and you could use the values from the model.  I've used this pattern with good success on a couple of projects.  Couple it with a base controller where the common properties are populated for view results in `OnActionExecuted()`, it can be very effective in both reducing code duplication and the use of *magic strings* in your views.

Model:

```
public abstract class CommonViewModel
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string UserDisplayName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Controller:

```
public abstract class BaseController
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted( ActionExecutedContext filterContext )
    {
        if (filterContext.Result is ViewResult)
        {
            var model = filterContext.ViewData.Model as CommonViewModel;
            if (model != null)
            {
                 model.CompanyName = Session["CompanyName"] as string;
                 model.UserDisplayName = Session["UserDisplayName"] as string;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Master Page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage<Foo.CommonViewModel>" %>
<!-- ... -->
<div>
   <%: Model.CompanyName %>
</div>
<!-- ... -->
<div>
   <%: Model.UserDisplayName %>
</div>
```